# is the theorem of Pythagoras right?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

We don't know if the theorem of Pythagoras is right or not because we have to find a way to size things correctly, and to prove it or disprove it, and the angle too, we have to draw an right triangle correctly.

Comment: how can we determine the size of a milimeter or centimeter or meter how do they do that

Comment: We live on a sphere. If we use flat ground to draw a triangle on, Pythagoras theorem will indeed be wrong. That can help us to understand the impact of us living in curved spacetime, in Minkowski space. If there is no local gravity, spacetime is flat. But obviously there is local gravity. For a longer time Euclidean geometry was assumed to be correct, and the curvature of the Earth was not factored in. We should be cautious about what we know and how well we know it.

Comment: Neither the statement of the Pythagorean theorem nor the definitions of the terms involved make references to drawings, so why do you think its truth would be related to ones ability to draw? Also, the question in your comment is about metrology, which is part of [physics.se], not philosophy.

Comment: how do you say in english stroking a triangule i thought drawing was the word

Comment: Eli Maor's [book](https://www.amazon.com/Pythagorean-Theorem-000-Year-History-Princeton/dp/0691148236?dplnkId=9b75a633-dea2-4348-8502-c74f85da1606) (didn't read it) holds 371 proofs of it.

Comment: Drawing is the correct word for what you're trying to say. I was asking why you think that (a visual aid) is relevant to the actual mathematical content of the theorem.

Comment: @joseph Yes, we should not claim that the Pythagoras theorem is true, because it is  not. However, we can claim that if all the presuppositions on which the theorem is motivated are or were true, then the theorem is or would be true. Mathematicians never prove their conclusions true, they prove them conditionally, that is, on the assumption that all their presuppositions are true. Mathematical "geometry" has little to do with actual geometry, i.e., the science of measuring the land, the expertise of land surveyors. The Pythagoras theorem is not about the geometry of land surveyors.

Comment: well its important to draw a triangule well because thats the way we can prove it or disprove it

Comment: maybe im making a discovery

Comment: why my post are always remove we havent prove the theoremor disprove it

Comment: i havent made the experiment

Comment: An inch is defined to be three barleycorns long, it's the most precise unit of measurement I know of. Integers have infinite precision. "*Measure with a micrometer, mark with chalk, cut with an axe.*"

Comment: maybe the theorem is right but i have to test it

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it is 'Pythagoras', not 'Pithagoras'.

Second, the theorem has nothing to do with units of measurement, as @joseph seems to think.

Third, we always assume we -can- draw our diagrams correctly.  This is actually NOT a physical act of drawing, it is a theoretical act.  The pictures we draw physically are only meant to be aids to our understanding, they are not to be taken literally (in fact, the ancient Greeks would actually make certain 'errors' - like drawing a straight line, such as the chord in a circle, actually curved - in order to prevent anyone from implicitly making assumptions based on features of the drawing).

Fourth, have you ever actually READ one of the many proofs?  Doing so might help you understand better.

Comment: Well technically it's Πῡθαγόρᾱς. All the rest is subject to conventions about converting ancient Greek to modern English.

Comment: im gonna try to prove it or disprove it but imgonna search about sizes in goole to seeif it is correct and angles too how to draw them well

Comment: what is a diagram